# Activity shows before moving to another activity while using datastore to check for saved preferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack-datastore

I am using the new DataStore to save user Preferences in Android App.

I am trying to show an intro activity for first time users.

Problem - After saving the preference using data store, I then check to see if there is a saved preference already - If yes - Move to the next activity.
The problem is that the Intro Activity shows slightly before moving to the next activity which is definitely a bad UI/UX.

This doesn't happen when I used SharedPreferences.

**IntroActivity**

```
 private var hasSeenIntro: Boolean = true 
 .......

 //I also used a splash screen, but the activity still shows slightly.
 setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


  dataManager.hasSeenIntro.asLiveData().observe(this){
        hasSeenIntro = it
        if(hasSeenIntro){
            val intent = Intent(this, RegisterOrLoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
```

**DataManager**

```
private val dataStore = context.createDataStore("data_prefs")

companion object{
    val HAS_SEEN_INTRO = preferencesKey<Boolean>("HAS_SEEN_INTRO")
}

suspend fun storeHasSeenIntro(intro: Boolean){
    dataStore.edit {data->
        data[HAS_SEEN_INTRO] = intro
    }
}

val hasSeenIntro : Flow<Boolean> = dataStore.data.map {
    it[HAS_SEEN_INTRO] ?: false
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to put it in on Splash Screen and put that condition in delay. That will work.

Comment: How do I do that.?.I have already implemented a splash screen. The splash screen first shows then the IntroActivity quickly shows before heading to the RegisterOrLoginActivity.
I dont want the IntroActivity to show at all.

Comment: @Ibramazin Did you found a solution?

Comment: @AmrJyniat oh, according to Florina Muntenescu (Android Dev Advocate at Google), she said this is an expected behaviour because DataStore is async while SharedPrefs is sync. 

DataStore doesn't block the UI while retrieving the data like SharedPrefs is.